# How to use $inject for declaration of angular dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an MVC application with angular JS. I have enabled the minification of scripts using

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

in the BundleConfig.cs. To avoid minification of dependency variable I used injection as given below.

```
app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'HomeService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', HomeController]);
```

HomeController is the name of the function. It is working fine. Recently I found that, we can user controllerName.$inject to do the same. SO I tried it as given below.

```
HomeController.$inject['$scope', 'HomeService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder'];
```

It didn't worked for me. Before doing this, I tried this method in a test project with only $scope variable. it worked. So what is the issue and how can I fix this. Please help me.

Comment: can you provide sampe how you try use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see in [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation)

`$inject` is a property that you should fill, like this

```
HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'HomeService', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder'];
```